# Creating new SoapObject Blows up android app

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I'm new to ksoap2 and I'm trying to get example w3 schools example working. For some reason it always fails on this line.

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

I dont know what is causing the fail. The android app just blows up. I have set internet permisions in Manifest. Im not really sure what is going on. Thanks

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class WebServiceTurorialActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    (findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    int a;
    int b;
    try
    { 
        // EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        // EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
        // a = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
        // b = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString()); 

         SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
         //Request.addProperty("a", a);
        // Request.addProperty("b", b);
         Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

         SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
         soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

         HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
         SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

         Toast.makeText(this,"200 " + resultString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }catch(Exception ex) {
         Toast.makeText(this,"FALSE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: blows up = you have an error? Please provide logcat / stacktrace of that.

Comment: ok here is the link to logcat

Comment: http://www.sourcepod.com/fnbryw34-7289

Comment: @PavelP  :Is is working now or do you still have a problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. That works for me:

As the prev answer said:

- In your build path clear all libraries (jar files).
- In project's main directory create a folder and named it "libs" (not "lib").
- Now Eclipse ADT Plugin will add your jar files to build path

Not realy for me. My way:

1. In your build path remove the "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.x.x-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
2. Click OK (Ignore Errors shown)
3. In project's main directory create a folder "libs"
4. Copy the JAR-File into this directory (!)
5. In your build path add the JAR file with this directory

Answer (score 3):

For everyone having also this problem... I was trying to solve this problem for many many hours, but then I detected what my fault was: I did not correctly download the ksoap2 library, so there was only a jar file which was 21 KB, but the correct jar file is about 150KB. So make sure that you download the file correctly!

Answer (score 1):

- In your build path clear all libraries (jar files).
- In project's main directory create a folder and named it "libs" (not
  "lib").
- Now Eclipse ADT Plugin will add your jar files to build path.
- Happy coding

If you still get the same problem, try these classes (works for me):

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String fahrenheit = CelsiusToFahrenheitWs.celsiusToFahrenheit("32");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fahrenheit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class CelsiusToFahrenheitWs {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

    public static String celsiusToFahrenheit(String celsius) {
        String fahrenheit = null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius", celsius);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            fahrenheit = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fahrenheit = null;
        }
        return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the program still crashes. I placed the jar file into libs folder and I still get the same error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject. I tried a different ksoap2 jar file but that did not fix the problem. Im still searching for a solution. Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem, the reason was also an incomplete jar file. It worked if I downloaded the raw file of the version, you can find this by going to the details of the versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an another SOAP library to call SOAP services on Android, the name of the project is AndroidSOAP ( http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home ).

I've released a version 0.0.5 today, check it out: http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/2012/05/01/Version+0.0.5+released

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools.com is no more accepting NAMESPACE as tempuri.org which caused SOAP exception in the code. You need to use "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/" for NAMESPACE and "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" for SOAP_ACTION.

Hope this is help!